# nginx + uwsgi 502 Bad Gateway python

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I'm running a script in python and takes a long time to process. The thing is if the function takes to long to run, i guess the nginx has a timeout, in his configuration and that prevents somekind of errors, and prevents the function to run completely.

I just want to know were i can increse the value of the timeout. Because i've tried some commands in the file conf of nginx such as:

```
uwsgi_connect_timeout 75;
uwsgi_send_timeout 75;
uwsgi_read_timeout 75;
keepalive_timeout 650;
```

but none of this worked.

Thks in advance

Comment: How long does your script take to run? `75` isn't a lot more than the default `60`. Based on [the docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUwsgiModule#uwsgi_read_timeout), `uwsgi_read_timeout` is the one you want to change.

Comment: Also curious as to what your script does. You may be able to increase the timeout for nginx, but most users won't be hanging around that long.

Comment: basically is a script that runs a db with 500 users, and using that i use geocode that gives me the longitude and the latitude of the address of the user. With thar i insert on a mongodb collections. The ting is because geocode fails sometimes, i have to do this procedure 3 times more to know all the users adress geolocation.

Comment: Still, it would be nice to know how to prevent nginx from timing out. I've got a long running script that I'm using in development, so optimization isn't a concern for me. I just want the page to load, but can't find the magic combination of settings to prevent nginx from throwing a 502.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with just extending the timeout is that no matter how much longer you set it to you will run into limitations somewhere along the line. Either with the web server, the browser or your geocode calls. If it is something that routinely fails n times in a request, then you can't really make any guarantees.

So rather than having the client request hanging on a long running process (and by extension risking a server timeout), why don't you use something like [celery](http://celeryproject.org/) to run those geocode tasks and on the client-side, submit your client-side request via javascript and poll the server for the answer via [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) until it get's a response?

Comment: I've got a very good reason for wanting a longer timeout. It's a one-time only import task the client needs to do on a pre-production server and rewriting the code to work as a background task would take considerably longer than simply increasing the timeout temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

I also had Bad gateway error in NGIX + uWSGI configuration, and for sake of people who google this question: it might be missing uwsgi python plugin. Please see: [uWSGI configuration issue: uwsgi fails without any error message.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770239/).

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything written in the above response as well as other places but they did not work.

My solution was changing my socket in both the uwsgi.conf and nginx.conf files.