# uWSGI configuration issue: uwsgi fails without any error message.

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

When configuring uwsgi django application for first time i had weird error. NGIX (configured as per documentation) responded with `502 Bad Gateway response`.

Uwsgi logs give no apparent error:

```
  Sun Oct  7 17:36:31 2012 - *** Starting uWSGI 1.2.3-debian (64bit) on [Sun Oct  7 17:36:31 2012] ***
  Sun Oct  7 17:36:31 2012 - compiled with version: 4.7.1 on 13 September 2012 19:07:14
  Sun Oct  7 17:36:31 2012 - detected number of CPU cores: 2
  Sun Oct  7 17:36:31 2012 - current working directory: /
  Sun Oct  7 17:36:31 2012 - writing pidfile to /run/uwsgi/app/lfitjcmsjb/pid
  Sun Oct  7 17:36:31 2012 - detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
  Sun Oct  7 17:36:31 2012 - setgid() to 33
  Sun Oct  7 17:36:31 2012 - setuid() to 33
  Sun Oct  7 17:36:31 2012 - your memory page size is 4096 bytes
  Sun Oct  7 17:36:31 2012 - detected max file descriptor number: 1024
  Sun Oct  7 17:36:31 2012 - lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
  Sun Oct  7 17:36:31 2012 - uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /run/uwsgi/app/lfitjcmsjb/socket fd 3
  Sun Oct  7 17:36:31 2012 - uwsgi socket 1 bound to UNIX address /tmp/lfitj.sock fd 5
  Sun Oct  7 17:36:31 2012 - your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
  Sun Oct  7 17:36:31 2012 - *** Operational MODE: preforking ***
  Sun Oct  7 17:36:31 2012 - *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
  Sun Oct  7 17:36:31 2012 - *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
  Sun Oct  7 17:36:31 2012 - spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 5141)
  Sun Oct  7 17:36:31 2012 - spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 5144, cores: 1)
  Sun Oct  7 17:36:31 2012 - spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 5145, cores: 1)
  Sun Oct  7 17:37:57 2012 - -- unavailable modifier requested: 0 --
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uWSGI logs show error --- it is:

```
 -- unavailable modifier requested: 0 --
```

which basically means that python plugin is missing --- you need to install it. On debian you need to install `uwsgi-plugin-python`.